# Swipe Actions are not working on Section header

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift4.2

I am using swift 4.2 and xcode 10.1. I am working on a project and Created some fancy expand/Collapsable UITableView.

Everything is working just fine and awesome. Then there comes some need of introducing some swipe actions. So it looks so easy to create them here is how I am using and creating them

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Add") { (action, view, handler) in
        print("Add Action Tapped")
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .green
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    return configuration
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, handler) in
        print("Delete Action Tapped")
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    return configuration
}
```

But that is not working on my sections. The row gets swipable actions when I swipe them left or right. but No on my section headers. Here is how I am creating view for my section header.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! HeaderCell

    let shoppingList = mDataSource[section]

    let itemCount = shoppingList.ShoppingItems.count

    let txtStoreName = shoppingList.Store.P_FriendlyName! + " (\(itemCount))"

    cell.lblName.text = txtStoreName

    let imageHollow  = UIImage(named: "checkbox_hollow") // For List Item Check box image

    cell.btnSelectHeader.setImage(imageHollow, for: .normal)

    if(shoppingList.IsSelected){
        let imageChecked  = UIImage(named: "checkbox_checked") // For List Item Check box image
        cell.btnSelectHeader.setImage(imageChecked, for: .normal)
    }



    if(shoppingList.IsExpanded){

        let image  = UIImage(named: "ic-indicator-up")

        cell.ivIndicatorExpandCollapse.image = image

        cell.viewContentView.backgroundColor = CommonUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: AppColors.colorItemSelector)


    }else{

        let image  = UIImage(named: "ic-indicator-down")

        cell.ivIndicatorExpandCollapse.image = image

        cell.viewContentView.backgroundColor = CommonUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: AppColors.colorWhite)
    }


    cell.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    cell.isCellSwipable = IS_CELL_RIGHT_SWIPEABLE
    cell.delegateHeader = self
    cell.clickedSection = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: section)
    cell.clickedModel = shoppingList


    return cell

}
```

**Problems:** here are my problems and questions

- Section headers are not showing swipe actions as other cells are showing.
- Are these swipe actions are available from iOS 11.0 up to latest or it will only work on iOS 11 only?

Please help me I am not sure why it is not working on section headers????

Comment: if i'm not wrong then `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` this action only applicable to `uitableviewcell` not to `sectionHeader which is UIView`. so i think you have to add swipe gesture to your sectionHeader.

Comment: ok, but then How to show exactly same views behind the section view as other rows are doing ?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, iOS does not allow to swipe section headers. I would like to recommend use your own logic. You can manage by changing view constraints (default view or swiped view) yourself for section header.

```
   func sectionSwiped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let viewSwiped = gestureRecognizer.view as? UIView{
        swipedSection = viewSwiped.tag
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let vw = UIView()
    vw.tag = section
    //You can customize view
    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "sectionSwiped:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    vw.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    return vw
}
```

Comment: Please give some example. I dod not really got you

Comment: Use swipe gesture (left & right) on section view. Whenever user swipes section, you can get section number from gesture and store it in variable and reload section of table view. In viewheader method of tableview, you need to check if current section is same as stored section then you need to display swiped UI.

Comment: well I know how to use UIGestureRecognizer, but the logic you mentioned below I did not get it. please show me some example code

Comment: func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if let viewSwiped = gestureRecognizer.view as? UIView{
               swipedSection = viewSwiped.tag
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let vw = UIView()
vw.tag = section
//You can customize view
return vw
    }

Comment: what is viewSwiped, Please show me proper code example

Comment: Please find following code

func sectionSwiped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       
    if let viewSwiped = gestureRecognizer.view as? UIView{
               swipedSection = viewSwiped.tag
        }
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let vw = UIView()
vw.tag = section
//You can customize view
var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "sectionSwiped:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    vw.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
return vw
    }

Comment: ok got it, but as I am using Swipe Actions on rows, so i want to make header look like same, though I will use you above mention procedure, but can it show icons beneath it while swiping right and left. in this way user will be get to know that there is no difference between them.

Comment: In simple words, using your idea, I want to replicate procedure of showing actions

Comment: It is better way to keep consistancy. So you need to use custom actions for cells as well like you do for sections. So it will look same whatever you do.

Comment: ok last question, can you show me how to reveal button beneath the moving header view